# MySQL Join Statement on a simple database

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench

I have a DB containing popular devices and brands for mobile operators.

I want to make one join query for selecting the most popular MODELS for and account + brand;

```
   SELECT m1.name FROM
    models as m1 
     JOIN accounts_to_models as am1
      ON m1.id = am1.FK_model_id

    JOIN brands as br 
    on br.id = m1.FK_brand_id

     JOIN accounts as ac
    on ac.id = am1.FK_account_id

    WHERE ac.name = "Operator" and b1.name = "HTC"
    ORDER BY am1.priority desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the join on `brands` is wrong as is the join on `accounts`.  Try this:

```
SELECT m1.name
FROM models m1 JOIN
     accounts_to_models am1
     ON m1.id = am1.FK_model_id JOIN
     brands as b1 
     ON b1.id = m1.FK_brand_id JOIN
--------------------^
     accounts as ac
     on ac.id = am1.FK_account_id
-----------^
WHERE ac.name = 'Operator' and b1.name = 'HTC'
ORDER BY am1.priority desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: @user2988649 . . . That was a typo.  It should have been `m1` as per the data model that you originally had in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are equating **ac.name** with **am1.FK_account_id** in third join. So . i think you need to write :

```
ac.id = am1.FK_account_id
```